# Php pdo UPDATE function with jquery ajax

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, syntax-error

I have this code php pdo for update value into datatabase:

```
try {        
                $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
                $STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE track_aktivnosti SET vrednost = :4, WHERE id_akt = :1, naziv = :3, datum = :2");

                $STH->bindParam(':1', $_POST['ajdi']);
                $STH->bindParam(':2', $_POST['datum']);
                $STH->bindParam(':3', $_POST['tabela']);
                $STH->bindParam(':4', $_POST['vrednost']);
```

but I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id_akt =
>   '25', naziv = 'Laza Lazic', datum = '2013-04-01'' at line 1
>
> Data
>   submitted successfully

What is can be probem here? Why I cant update `vrednost` with this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple errors:

1) Get rid of the comma before your WHERE clause:

```
SET vrednost = :4, WHERE id_akt = :1
               ^^^^
               HERE
```

2) Get rid of the commas in your `WHERE` clause. The correct syntax is to use `AND` (or `OR`):

```
WHERE id_akt = :1, naziv = :3, datum = :2"
              ^^^^^       ^^^^^
              HERE        HERE
```

should be:

```
WHERE id_akt = :1 AND naziv = :3 AND datum = :2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove comma before your where clause and use conditional operators like (AND/OR)

```
UPDATE track_aktivnosti SET vrednost = :4
 WHERE id_akt = :1 AND naziv = :3 AND datum = :2
```